Keycloak: [invalid_token_response] An error occurred while attempting to retrieve the OAuth 2.0 Access Token Response
I am trying to integrate a Spring Boot application with Keycloak for OAuth2 authentication, but I am running into an issue where the user is not properly redirected after logging in and I get an error message.
[invalid_token_response] An error occurred while attempting to retrieve the OAuth 2.0 Access Token Response: I/O error on POST request for "https://<KEYCLOAK_SERVER>/realms/oauth-AD/protocol/openid-connect/certs": PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target

I getting this error on the browser site after login.
Spring application and Keycloak have necessary certificates.
My question: What is the problem and do you know how to fix this?
My code:
SecurityConfig.java
public class SecurityConfig {

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain setFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        http
                .csrf(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
                .oauth2Client(Customizer.withDefaults())
                .oauth2Login(Customizer.withDefaults())
                .authorizeHttpRequests((authorizeHttpRequests) -> authorizeHttpRequests
                        .requestMatchers(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/role/visiter")).hasRole("ROLE_VISITER")

                        .requestMatchers(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/index/**")).permitAll()
                        .anyRequest().authenticated());
        return http.build();
    }

    @Bean
    public ClientRegistrationRepository clientRegistrationRepository() {
        ClientRegistration dummyRegistration = ClientRegistration.withRegistrationId("keycloak-oauth2")
                .clientId("dummy-client-id")
                .clientSecret("dummy-client-secret")
                .authorizationGrantType(AuthorizationGrantType.AUTHORIZATION_CODE)
                .redirectUri("https://localhost:8443/login/oauth2/code/keycloak")
                .issuerUri("https://keycloak.example.com/realms/myrealm")
                .authorizationUri("https://keycloak.example.com/realms/myrealm/protocol/openid-connect/auth")
                .scope("openid", "email", "profile", "roles")
                .tokenUri("https://keycloak.example.com/realms/myrealm/protocol/openid-connect/token")
                .userInfoUri("https://keycloak.example.com/realms/myrealm/protocol/openid-connect/userinfo")
                .jwkSetUri("https://keycloak.example.com/realms/myrealm/protocol/openid-connect/certs")
                .build();
        return new InMemoryClientRegistrationRepository(dummyRegistration);
    }

}

application.properties
spring.application.name=demo

#Server Konfiguration
server.port=8443
server.error.whitelabel.enabled=false
server.error.path=/error

# Logging Configuration
logging.level.org.springframework.security=DEBUG

#Keystore
server.ssl.enabled=true
server.ssl.key-store=classpath:localhost.jks
server.ssl.key-store-type=jks
server.ssl.key-store-password=<password>
server.ssl.protocol=TLSv1.3

#Truststore
server.ssl.trust-store=classpath:localhost.jks
server.ssl.trust-store-type=jks
server.ssl.trust-store-password=<password>

I have blacked out the Keycloak Server Name and the ssl password.
I haven't had any solutions yet.

server.ssl.key-store=classpath:localhost.jks
If you are referencing the classpath variable then shouldn't it be $CLASSPATH for both the above mentioned configuration and the server.ssl.trust-store variable?

The application does not start with $CLASSPATH, but it does with classpath.
